# WinRt prevent selected item from binding when null

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a list view that has a binding from SelectedItem to a property (lets call it person) on my view model.

I would like to prevent the binding from taking place when it is null.

Currently when i clear the Items collection this is causing selection changed to bind back null.

I know i could put a null check on persons setter from within the view model but i'd prefer not to.

Can the same be achieved using a converter?

```
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //Something like this?
        if(value == null) ABORT BINDING SOMEHOW
        else return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about preventing it on the setter of SelectedPerson. Why do you need to prevent the binding?

```
public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _selectedPerson = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to use the setter on Person as I dont really want to write a test to cover this binding issue. The list is a result set for some autocomplete items. When i clear the text box, its returning an empty list and firing off seleteditem changed and binding null which i dont want.

Comment: Then why not handle SelectedItemChanged. Keep the last correct item binded and if the new one is null, assign the old one. Does it sound better?

Comment: I'm using the MVVM pattern, so again would prefer to avoid the code behind, especially when it's unnecessary, but thanks.